# Check if user is online in PHP: What I'm doing wrong here?

Tags: php, mysql

```
function checkUserStatus($uid) {
    $q = "select last_activity from signup_and_login_table where id='$uid' LIMIT 1";
    $link=mysql_connect("localhost","mydbusr","mydbpass");
        mysql_select_db("mymaindb",$link);
    $ros=mysql_query($q,$link);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ros))
    {
        $last_activity =  $row['last_activity'];
        if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) > strtotime($last_activity) + 30 ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm updating the last_activity value on mysql each time the user refresh the page or or do another action.

**Why does the function above always return true and never return false even if the time difference between last_activity and now() is over 30 seconds ?**

The time in mysql is presented in this format : 2014-05-02 07:44:55

Any hints would be highly appreciated

Comment: You use `LIMIT 1` in your query. Therefore the `while` loop is useless - the query will always return only one or zero rows.

Comment: As mentioned above you are using limit 1, now if you be more specific and get it with desc/asce or w/e criteria then i think you can solve your problem

Comment: I don't understand the `strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))` section. Surely that's just... `time()`

Comment: when you use the limit, you must need the `order by` in query otherwise you got always  first row of table

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM signup_and_login_table WHERE id = :uid AND last_activity > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 SECOND)`

Answer (score 0):

You should change it into:

```
function checkUserStatus($uid) {

$q = "select last_activity from signup_and_login_table where id='$uid' ORDER BY last_activity DESC LIMIT 1";
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","mydbusr","mydbpass");
    mysql_select_db("mymaindb",$link);
$ros=mysql_query($q,$link);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($ros);

    $last_activity =  $row['last_activity'];
    if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) > strtotime($last_activity) + 30 ) {
    return false;
    } else {
    return true;
    }

}
```

You can only select 1 record but order it by last_activity DESC and simple compare it with current time

Comment: I think it is better to use `mysql_fetch_num` and `$row[0]`, because the query returns always only one row with one field.

Comment: `mysql_` is deprecated. Don't suggest it!

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to use the **`mysqli_*`** functions.

```
function checkUserStatus($uid) {
    $q = "select last_activity from signup_and_login_table where id='$uid' LIMIT 1";
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","mydbusr","mydbpass");
        mysqli_select_db("mymaindb",$link);

    $res = mysqli_query($link, $q);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_num($res);//this function returns the result in a numeric array

    return time() > strtotime($row[0]) + 30;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use "while Loop", you should use mysql_fetch_assoc() function as next:

```
function checkUserStatus($uid) {
    $q = "select last_activity from signup_and_login_table where id='$uid'";
    $link=mysql_connect("localhost","mydbusr","mydbpass");
        mysql_select_db("mymaindb",$link);
    $ros=mysql_query($q,$link);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($ros))
    {
        $last_activity =  $row['last_activity'];
        if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) > strtotime($last_activity) + 30 ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

OR you can try without loop:

```
function checkUserStatus($uid) {
    $q = "select last_activity from signup_and_login_table where id='$uid' LIMIT 1";
    $link=mysql_connect("localhost","mydbusr","mydbpass");
        mysql_select_db("mymaindb",$link);
    $ros=mysql_query($q,$link);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ros);
    $last_activity =  $row['last_activity'];
    if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) > strtotime($last_activity) + 30 ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```